# Should the debugger throw some warning when passing a derived class as a parameter?

Tags: c#, inheritance, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm working on ASP.NET Core and I'd found a *thing* about inheritance (since `IdentityUser` can be derived by `ApplicationUser`).

Here is just a demo to explain what it is:

Entities:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    // cat has no wings...
}

public class Eagle : Animal
{
    public object LeftWing { get; set; }
    public object RightWing { get; set; }
}
```

Database context (just for demo):

```
public void SaveChanges(Animal animal)
{
    // save changes for "Animals" table...
}
```

And use it:

```
var cat = new Cat { Name = "Norris" };
var eagle = new Eagle { Name = "Voldemort", LeftWing = "good", RightWing = "broken" };

SaveChanges(cat);
SaveChanges(eagle);

// in asp.net core, this can be:
// public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {}

// _dbContext.Users.Add(new ApplicationUser { ExtensionProperty = "foo" });

// but we forgot to update the "Users" table 
// which refers to "ApplicationUser" class instead if "IdentityUser" class by default
// _dbContext.Users.Add(new IdentityUser());
```

Since a cat has no wings, we don't need to *add* the left wing and the right's as the two properties.

Also, not all of animals have the wings, so they don't need to be defined in the table `Animals`.

To fix this *problem*, we can create two tables `Cats` and `Eagles`.

But in this post, I just want to mention about inheritance.

When dad can be replaced with son while son has 2 wings but dad has not?

Comment: Are you asking about table-per-type vs table-per-hierarchy? Do a search on those with keyword entity framework, there is enough material out there to answer your question (I think). If not reword your question because it is not clear at all what you are asking (to me anyways).

Comment: @Igor Oh. I'm sorry. I mean, when I've tried to update to database with some extension properties which is not defined in the table. The debugger doesn't throw any warning about it. It's still a valid action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it shouldn't.  You have stated that your method only needs an "Animal" to function.

If you need to know about wings, etc, then perhaps your contract is wrong?

In this case, perhaps animal is sufficient, and let an ORM (such as Entity Framework) work out how to persist it (i.e. in separate tables).

Comment: `then perhaps your contract is wrong?`. Yes, you know what I mean, thank you! but since `Cat` and `Eagle` are derived to `Animal`, I haven't received any warning/error message because of inheritance.

Comment: I wouldn't expect you to get a warning!  You chose Animal as your methods parameter type.  Your method should work with Animal!  If it doesn't, then you need to change your method signature.  By adding Animal to the signature, you have formed a contract and are stating to consumers you can handle all derived animals.